# How to pass beeline hive var for source command?

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline

I am trying to pass beeline variable. **source file name command** is not able to replace the variable with the value. Same command working using hive -f.Please find commands below.

Note:

```
cat >dev_env.hql
set hivevar:l1_gcb_trxn_db_path="hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/l1_app_gcb/process/l1_gcb_trxn";

SET hivevar:myvar=dev;
**source /data/1/appgcb/config/"${myvar}"_env.hql;**

create database l1_gcb_trxn
location ${l1_gcb_trxn_db_path} ;
```

**Error**

```
 jdbc:hive2://quickstart.cloudera:10000/def> source /data/1/appgcb/config/"${myvar}"_env.hql;
0: jdbc:hive2://quickstart.cloudera:10000/def> create database l1_gcb_trxn
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> location ${l1_gcb_trxn_db_path} ;
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:9 mismatched input '$' expecting StringLiteral near 'location' in database location specification (state=42000,code=40000)
```

**But hive -f is able to replace the variable.**

```
hive -f "${PROJECT_DIR}/tmp/create_db_l1_gcb_trxn.hql" --hivevar db_env=${db_env}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to hive using beeline but don't have access to manipulate anything there. below works for to get access to hive.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Executing the hive query - starts"

beeline --showHeader=true --outputformat=csv2 -u jdbc:hive2://hostname.com:10000 -n username -p password -e "select * from tablename limit 5;"


echo "Executing the hive query - ends"
```

Comment: create_db_l1_gcb_trxn.hql contains created db statement and db_env=${db_env} contains an env file. The answer you shared is not going to help here. Thanks for replying quickly.

Comment: Example below : Hive -f is running fine line=/data/1/appgcb/bin/app_gcb_dw/prccntrl/hql/ct_app_prc_run_cntl_stg_ld.hql
param_file=/data/1/appgcb/bin/app_gcb_dw/prccntrl/hql/param_file.hql
beeline_url=jdbc:hive2://quickstart.cloudera:10000/default

hive -f "${line}" --hivevar param_file=${param_file}
beeline -u $beeline_url -f "${line}" --hivevar param_file=${param_file} .

Comment: Working fine :: hive -f hive_source_test.hql --hivevar hive_var_file=${hive_var_file} 
Not working: beeline -u ${beeline_url} -f hive_source_test.hql --hivevar hive_var_file=${hive_var_file} . Not able to compile the variable  Error: 0: jdbc:hive2://quickstart.cloudera:10000/def> source ${hive_var_file};
Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://quickstart.cloudera:10000/default